# Passing data through a django FormWizard

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to build a django form wizard to allow people to register for an
event.  I can get through the form wizard and see data in the `done` method.
The problem is that I also need `event_id` passed into done also.  How do I get
`event_id` from the url through the form wizard and into `done`?   Simple example?

```
------- urls.py ---------
named_register_forms2 = (
    ('basicdata', SeatsForm),
    ('form2', AnotherForm),
)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^register/(?P<event_id>\d+)/$', register_wizard, name='register_step'),
)

------ forms.py -----------
class SeatsForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    fields = [ 'last_name', 'first_name', 'address1', 'address2', 
               'city', 'state', 'zipcode', 'phone_number', 'email']

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(SeatsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class RegisterWizard(SessionWizardView):
    #storage_name = 'formtools.wizard.storage.session.SessionStorage'
    template_name = 'wizard_form.html'

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        data = {}
        for form in form_list:
                data.update(form.cleaned_data)
                print data
        # I need event_id right here.  How to get it?
        return render_to_response('done.html', {
            'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
    })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you will have to put that in the form and get it from there.

If its model form you can pass `instance_dict` param to the wizard view. [instance_dict param](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.instance_dict). However in that case you will have to implement a wrapper view that will prepare the wizard view with these params. Something like this:

```
def wrapper_view(request, id):
    #somecode
    seats_instance = SeatsModel.objects.get(id=id)
    another_instance = AnotherModel.objects.get(id=id)
    inst_dict = { '0': seats_instance,
                  '1': another_instance
                }
    return RegisterWizard.as_view(named_register_forms2, instance_dict=inst_dict)(request)

class RegisterWizard(SessionWizardView):
    #storage_name = 'formtools.wizard.storage.session.SessionStorage'
    template_name = 'wizard_form.html'

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        data = {}
        seatform= form_list[0]
        seatinst = form.save()    
        #save other forms
        ...
        #using seatinst get event id

        return render_to_response('done.html', {
            'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
             })
```

Comment: What file do I put `wrapper_view` in and how do I call it?

Comment: @codingJoe something that gets `seats_instance` and `another_instance` either using `id` from parameter or `request.GET`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it.  What is `seats_instance`? and how do I put `id` in there?   Then how do I get `id` out in the done method?

Comment: Got it working.  Your comments were so helpful  also had to modify the wizard instance `myView = RegisterWizard.as_view([SeatsForm, AnotherForm], initial_dict=initial)`

Answer (score 4):

The question is two years old, but for completeness, I've been solving this problem by overriding the `dispatch` method of the wizard class. This method is called by the wizard with the raw arguments from the URL dispatcher. You can modify the wizard's `instance_dict` (and presumably any other wizard member) before anything else happens.

```
class RegisterWizard(SessionWizardView):
    #storage_name = 'formtools.wizard.storage.session.SessionStorage'
    template_name = 'wizard_form.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, id, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance_dict = {
            '0': SeatsModel.objects.get(id=id),
            '1': AnotherModel.objects.get(id=id),
        }
        return super(RegisterWizard, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        data = {}
        seatform= form_list[0]
        seatinst = form.save()    
        #save other forms
        ...
        #using seatinst get event id

        return render_to_response('done.html', {
            'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
        })
```

I'm not sure there is any major functional advantage, but it feels like the wizard is a little more encapsulated doing it this way. In addition I've no idea if this was the intended use of the `dispatch` method.

I suppose if one were to inherit `RegisterWizard` the behaviour of setting `instance_dict` with objects from `SeatsModel` and `AnotherModel` would be available without the need to make user of a wrapper function; that might be the only actual advantage of doing it this way.