# Django test client/test a view

Tags: django

this is my first post here. If i'm not doing it all correct at once please guide me. Thanks in advance.

In line with the tutorial([The Django test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial05/)) I have written the following test:

```
class HomePageTest(TestCase):
def test_home_page(self):
    response = self.client.get('/')
    print(response.status_code)
```

According to the Django docs:

> To resolve URLs, the test client uses whatever URLconf is pointed-to by your ROOT_URLCONF setting.

My urls.py:

```
# my_site/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include('apps.home.urls',namespace='home')),
    url(r'^product/', include('apps.product.urls', namespace='product')),
    url(r'^order/', include('apps.order.urls', namespace='order')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
]

# apps/home/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

My views.py:

```
# apps/home/views.py
class IndexView(generic.TemplateView):
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(self.request, 'base/index.html')

# apps/product/views.py
class ProductView(SessionWizardView):
template_name = 'product.html'

instance_dict = {
    'item': get_object_or_404(models.Product, name='Shifter'),
}
```

The expected outcome of the test is "200" for running:

```
test tests.HomePageTest --keepdb
```

Nevertheless i'm receiving an error:

> Http404: No Product matches the given query.

The error that occurs is because I haven't made any dummy instance of "Product".
I could do so in "def setUp(self)", but the request I send should lead to the app "home". The other apps shouldn't be called at all as the regex expression does not match.

Why is it even possible that the view of app "Product" is called?

Thanks in advance, Siggy

Comment: It looks like the `ProductView` is not being called. The `get_object_or_404` is running when the module is loaded, not when the test client makes the request. Try setting the `instance_dict` attribute in the `dispatch` method, as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26459029/113962).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It is indeed a solution. Nevertheless, why is the module loaded? As the `self.client.get('\')` should go to the app "home" it shouldn't even load the module 'apps.product.views' or does the URLconf first loads all views and then connect to the specific view where the regex has a match?

Comment: The module is loaded because your root url conf includes `apps.product.urls`, and then that `urls.py` imports the module.

Comment: So `apps.product.urls` is always loaded whatever the request is?

Comment: The urls are loaded once, not for every request. The `apps.product.urls` will be loaded at that point.

Comment: Thanks all clear now :)